# Parsing "Vous saurez vous en occuper"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I'm having trouble understanding this sentence (which appears in the comic in the [French rules](http://www.matagot.com/docs/Takenoko_rules_FR.pdf) for the board game Takenoko):

> Je suis certain que vous saurez vous en occuper.

The part that I'm having trouble understanding is:

> vous saurez vous en occuper.

This is how I approached understanding this:

- I understand "vous saurez" to be the typical subject-verb mini-sentence that can be built upon to create a more complicated sentence, just like "Je veux" or "Je mange" are simple mini-sentences that could be built upon. Using google translate helps me understand that "saurez" is the "vous" conjugation of "savoir".
- The second "vous", my guess, must be some kind of object pronoun (i.e., a direct object or indirect object pronoun)

This leaves "en occuper", and this is where I have trouble.

- Is "occuper" an infinitive that follows a conjugated semi-auxillary    verb, as if the sentence is "Vous saurez vous occuper" (which is a construction I'm familiar with, similar to "Je veux danser")? If so, what is that "en" (is it  another pronoun?)
- or is "en occuper" one unit, the way that I have seen "en + past-participle" (such as    "en dansant") be "one unit"?

---

(For those who like to hear about the difficulties a French Language Learner has: I'm realizing that pronouns that come directly before infinitives often confuse me; they aren't something that teaching materials talk a lot about. Another sentence from the same comic that I struggled with also uses a pronoun before an infinitive: "Je tenais à vous offrir le plus beau symbole du yin et du yang").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Vous vous occupez" comes from the verb ["s'occuper"](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlw-TojcDXAhWFChoKHSZTCO4QFggoMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.larousse.fr%2Fdictionnaires%2Ffrancais%2Fs_occuper%2F55513&usg=AOvVaw1aivLuB1aQd8ziQHoD-3Cs).

["en"](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/en/29044?q=en#28920) is a pronoun that replaces the object in the sentence :

> Je m'occupe de ma grand-mère -> Je m'en occupe.

Answer (score 0):

The second "vous" is a "pronom réfléchi", it's part of the verb and doesn't really have a function.